# Inequality constraints programmatically swift

Tags: swift, constraints

So I have completely coded the whole settings vc for my app using code (no storyboards) and I was wondering how do you make the constraints that you created inequality ones? Meaning that if the app is run on a iPhone 7 plus then the constraints would be as I coded them to be, however when you run the app on a iPhone se everything is on top of each other and not the right proportion. I only know how to do this in storyboards with using inequalities but how do you implement that in code? This is the first time that I am not using storyboards at all, so I am a little new.

Thank you in advance!

some code of what the constraints looks like:

```
func setupProfileImageView() {
    //need x, y, width, height constraints
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

}
```

Comment: *would be as I coded them to be*... well, it would be nice if you actually gave us some **code**.

Comment: I apologize for that I will edit it right now

Comment: Thanks. I'm not understanding what you mean still. You've defined (in code, like me) enough. top, with, height, and finally horizontal - centerX). What is the issue?

Comment: When I run the app on a iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 plus it looks great and just as expected, but when I run the app on an iPhone se all of my buttons/views etc are all on top of each other. And it would help if the top constraint moved up a but like instead of 120 if it was 80 or so. But I don't want to do that because it doesn't look right on an iPhone 7.

Comment: So what I am looking for is how to make it so that the constraint is less than or equal to 120 but no less than 60. Do you understand what I am talking about now? Thank you so much! and sorry for if I am not making much sense, I'm pretty tired but I need to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create two constraints - one for minimum (`greaterThanOrEqualTo`) and one for maximum (`lessThanOrEqualTo`).

```
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 120).isActive = true
```

There's a few tricks to do if you need set priorities, but it doesn't appear that you need to. If you've *placed* everything correctly (X and Y) this should do it.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to find this but I couldn't find where it was called.

Comment: So another question. Is it a problem to define two constraints for same anchor at the same time?

Comment: @Emre_Onder, Without seeing the specifics it's hard to say. Using `myButton.widthAnchor`, you have three options: (1) As above, create two `isActive = true` constraints that **do not** conflict. (2) Create two constraints but only have `isActive = true` for one at a time. And, of course, (3) Create two `isActive = true` constraints that **do** conflict and let the auto layout engine break one of them. Obviously, you don't want to do the third. If you ever find yourself stuck one where the conflict is, here's a link that may help: http://www.wtfautolayout.com

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest bet would be to stay with your methods, and apply a constant based on an algorithm. For example:

```
func setupProfileImageView() {
    //need x, y, width, height constraints

    var idealTop : CGFloat = view.frame.height * (some value) //so that it equals a value that changes with each screen size in a way that you feel ok with

    idealTop = idealTop < 60 ? 60 : idealTop //makes sure that the constraint doesnt fall bellow 60..

    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: idealTop).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

}
```

Second, I would recommend that for any layout that implies elements being vertically aligned and in the same level of view hierachy, to distance them by a similar way, and by making sure that each element's `topAnchor` refers to the element above it's `bottomAnchor`. A little trick you could do, is to store the value of your profileImage's topAnchor into a variable, so that you can access it's value for the other elements, like so:

```
var profileImageTopAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupProfileImageView() {
    //need x, y, width, height constraints

    var idealTop : CGFloat = view.frame.height * (some value) //so that it equals a value that changes with each screen size in a way that you feel ok with

    idealTop = idealTop < 60 ? 60 : idealTop //makes sure that the constraint doesnt fall bellow 60..

    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageTopAnchor = profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: idealTop)
    profileImageTopAnchor.isActive = true //otherwise it wont get activated
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

}
func setupProfileImageView() {

   let topAnchor = profileImageTopAnchor != nil ? profileImageTopAnchor!.constant : (/*Some arbitrary value here .. or repeat as above with a fraction value of the view.frame*/)

    let topAnchorValue : CGFloat = topAnchor * (some value) //this way, the spacing will change based on the spacing you declare on top of your image..

    //And say that you have three other elements stacked vertically..

    elementA.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.topAnchor, constant: topAnchorValue).isActive = true
    elementB.constraint(equalTo: elementA.topAnchor, constant: topAnchorValue).isActive = true
    elementC.constraint(equalTo: elementB.topAnchor, constant: topAnchorValue).isActive = true
}
```

You could go further into detecting the actual screen size, and correlating that with a list to see which phone model is being used.. to then apply specific constraints.. but as this sentence is getting longer, so are the reasons as to why the method above is more straightforward!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I’m a tad bit confused, what is “element a” and the other ones? Are they like other views maybe perhaps a label? Thanks again! I will try this when I am at my computer and get back to you.

Comment: So I tried what you did but it doesn't seem to be working. However since everything is connected to the bottom constraint of the view before it, when you change the constant of the profileImageView everything changes perfectly. So what I was thinking is to have a function that determines what iPhone a person is using and then having a if statement that changes the constant idealTop. However I am not sure what the syntax would look like?

Comment: yeah element a/b/c are different views, UILabel, UIButton, etc etc. Also which part doesn't seem to work?

Comment: It never did anything. The profile Image view isn't even showing up on the screen. It was probably my fault if I did something wrong.

Comment: I had made a typo.. forgot to replace 120 with `idealTop` inside of `profileImageTopAnchor = profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: idealTop)`. Did you fix it beforehand? if not try it now